# How I can do download the virtual machine for install 64bit programs in 32bit computer?

Tags: show

Same as Title. How I can do download the virtual machine for install 64bit programs in 32bit computer?
I just hope to download and operate Tensorflow and python 3.7 in 32bit computer too.

Comment: Review: Can you elaborate on how you get stuck? eg with screenshots or error messages? - what have you tried so far and what were the results?

Comment: @H.Hasenack   The error massages said 32 bit Windows hosts are not supported by this VirtualBox release

Comment: Seems highly unlikely to me that you can run a 64bit VM on a 32bit Host, neither that you can run 64bit apps on a 32bit host or 32bit VM, due to hardware differences (64bit (virtual) CPU address bus instead of 32 bit address bus) . But I am not an python expert. Running 32 bit on a 64bit VM or Host is usually possible.